# What is the purpose of using trap table

Tags: operating-system, system

I have a question when reading OSTEP. The question is how does the trap know which code to run inside the OS? I understand that is a terrible idea, cause it means user can do anything in the kernel. But I'm not clear the example given in the book "Imagine jumping into code to access a file, but just after permission check" Can anyone explain this? And also what will happen if a program can directly issue system call without using trap table? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *trap table* is what is conventionally used by the *system call handler* to invoke the requested operating service routine. It is a table that is protected by the kernel, so does not enable execution at an arbitrary address.  Rather it *maps* a requested service (typically a small number, search /usr/include for syscall.h) to a function that provides that service.

The application performs some operation like:

```
_open:
mov   $_SYS_OPEN, %r0
syscall
jmp-on-carry seterrno
ret
```

The bit of code in the kernel that gets invoked on the syscall operator does something like:

```
int n;
if ((n = Proc->reg[0]) < 0 || n >= _N_SYSCALLS) {
    return seterror(Proc, ENOSYS);
} else {
    return (*sys_call_table[n])(Proc);
}
```

The details vary by which os you are working with, but the overall idea is the same, and has remained relatively constant since the 1970s.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I am a fellow student studying this section chapter as well. I was also confused exactly this issue as well. However I found this slide deck online to help me.

[https://my.eng.utah.edu/~cs5460/slides/Lecture03.pdf](https://my.eng.utah.edu/%7Ecs5460/slides/Lecture03.pdf)

(Side note: As of the time of this posting, lectures 1 through 24 are available, it seems the class is not public. Big thanks to Prof. John Regehr anyway!)

To summarize my understanding, trap calls for individual system calls, such as read an I/O, fork a process, etc do not exist. Instead we use one trap, to represent the class of instructions. When this "system call" trap is called, the hardware preforms a context switch from user mode to kernel mode. But since only 1 trap is defined for system calls, the kernel then needs to know which operation to do for the application, (again read, fork etc), as well as the parameters for that system call instruction. (By this I mean when the system call trap is executed, the parameters are in specified registers in the CPU for the kernel to read.)

To solve this problem, We could have the user mode application pass a direct memory reference to the instruction it wants to execute as well as the parameters for it (For example, memory address 0x8F0FA in kernel space could be the entry point to the read function). So when the context switch occurs, the hardware places the kernel PC directly at the system call instruction need. This is a bad idea, since if the User mode could pass memory locations to run code in the kernel space... then the User mode application could call any kernel instruction directly, bypassing the security and safety of the Operating System. We need some kind of limit to this functionality.

The better solution is using a trap table. Instead of the direct memory location of the function required, the user mode app passes a "mapped key" to the system call trap instead of the "direct kernel instruction". These keys are made publicly available to user mode applications after the boot of the system. The hardware, instead of placing the PC at an arbitrary memory location, will always place the kernel instead at the trap handler function. That function will then take that mapped key and find the exact system call function in the privatized values of the trap table needed by the application.

If that doesn't help, check out the slide deck!

Edit: I made a mistake, traps are not called after a application is already in kernel mode. Traps are used to make the switch.