# Trap Table: what is it, and is it controlled by the OS?

Tags: operating-system

I am currently learning about Trap Table in my OS class. My questions is:

- What is trap table?
- Who is controlling the trap table?

**Here is my guess**

Trap table holds information of **how** a trap is handled. Since the same types of traps occour more than once, we store them in a table to keep controll of the "protocol"

I would also guess that the OS is in charge of the trap table (?) But it could also make sence that the hardware controlls this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/63912466/1701776

Comment: Yes, OS is in charge, as you may run different OS's on same PC, and run a different OS in a virtual machine on host OS